# Problema da compilação de código em C no VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Eu fiz todos os passos necessários para compilar o o C no VS Code, desde as extensões necessárias até o MinGW, variáveis do sistema, fiz tudo certo, mas sempre que tento compilar isso acontece:

[image: Clique aqui para visualizar a imagem]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver, por favoor!!

Comment: você reiniciou o computador após o setup do MinGW? lembro de ter visto algum problema relacionado a isso. Edit: há algumas alternativas como respostas em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848357/createprocess-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: reiniciei várias vezes